# How to change the parameters for a task with known task and tasklist ids

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tasks-api

I would like use Apps Script to make changes to the status, dates, or note of a task with known id.

I have tried using the following code which shows a change in status when I log the task in the script but the task is not updated in the calendar

```
task = Tasks.Tasks.get(tasklistID, taskid)

task.setStatus("completed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to modify "the status, dates, or note of a task", how about using the patch method of Tasks API?

**In order to use the sample script, before you run the script, please enable Tasks API at Advanced Google Services and API console. Please confirm it at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55588584).**

#### Sample script:

This sample script modifies the status, dates and note of a task of `taskId` in a list of `tasklistId`.

```
var tasklistId = "###";
var taskId = "###";
var resource = {
  status: "completed", // This is either "needsAction" or "completed"
  due: "2019-04-15T00:00:00Z", // Due date of the task (as a RFC 3339 timestamp).
  notes: "sample note",
}
var res = Tasks.Tasks.patch(resource, tasklistId, taskId);
```

- status: Status of the task. This is either "needsAction" or "completed".
- due: Due date of the task (as a RFC 3339 timestamp). Optional.
- notes: Notes describing the task. Optional.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that you have already known `tasklistId` and `taskId`.

#### References:

- [Tasks: patch](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/patch)
- [Resource representations](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks#resource)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

### Edit:

When you want to back the completed task to "needsAction". Please use the following script.

#### Sample script:

```
var resource = {
  status: "needsAction",
  completed: null,
};
Tasks.Tasks.patch(resource, tasklistId, taskId);
```

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, that's exactly what I was after

Comment: @Sheils Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Just noticed that the patch don't work when I try to reset the task to incomplete with status:needsAction I get an error Execution failed: API call to tasks.tasks.patch failed with error: Invalid Value. Can you address that in a one liner or should I make a new post

Comment: @Sheils I added a sample script for resetting status to "needsAction". Could you please confirm it?